# Prove that $\forall x \neg P(x) \iff \neg \exists x P(x)$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic

I am reading Velleman's "How to Prove it", and in one example he proves

$\neg \exists x P(x)  \implies \forall x \neg P(x)$

in the following way:

Suppose $\neg \exists x P(x)$.
Let x be arbitrary.
**Suppose $P(x)$**.
Since we have a specific $x$ for which P(x) is true, it follows that $\exists x P(x)$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $\neg P(x)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $\forall x \neg P(x)$, so $\neg \exists x P(x)  \implies \forall x \neg P(x)$

What makes me confused is the line in bold text, that is "Suppose $P(x)$". The reason is that he writes that he is doing proof by contradiction, but $P(x) \not\iff \neg\forall x \neg P(x)$. He is not treating all possible cases where $\forall x \neg P(x)$ is false by assuming $P(x)$, does he? So how can this be a valid proof by contradiction?

Edit: I deleted my first example since it was clearly not representative for the problem.

Edit 2: So the thing that I am opposing I guess is that $\neg \forall x \neg P(x)$ is not $P(x)$. And from what I have undestood, a proof by contradiction should use the negation of the consequent which I do not think that Velleman does.

Comment: The fact that $x$ is arbitrary is what allows us to use the $\forall$ quantifier and to conclude. In your example, $x$ is not arbitrary since you set $x$ to be equal to $7$.

Comment: You can't "assume $x=7$" and then infer that whatever you prove holds for all $x$ :)

Comment: As Augustin point out, the key here is to chose an arbitrary $x$,  saying it is arbitrary means you are not assuming any special condition about it, it means "$x$ can be anything (of the universe you are dealing with)"

Comment: As a note, there's a difference between proving a negation by deriving a contradiction and proof *by* contradiction.  The proof above is not a proof by contradiction.  Possibly proof by contradiction is used by Velleman for the opposite direction (which would be a shame as this is constructively true).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the point, in some detail: Given $\neg\exists x P(x)$, we want to show that $\forall x \neg P(x)$. Pick an $x$, any $x$: we want to show that $\neg P(x)$. From this we can conclude that, as $x$ was arbitrary, $\forall x \neg P(x)$ holds. By way of contradiction, suppose the thing we want to prove of $x$ is false — namely, suppose $\neg\neg P(x)$, or, what's equivalent in classical logic, $P(x)$. Well, now we have a problem: this can't be, as it contradicts $\neg\exists x P(x)$. $P(x)$ implies a contradiction, thus we can infer that $\neg P(x)$.

**It follows that $\neg P(x)$ after all**. Here's why: It's a tautology that $(p \to \neg p) \to \neg p$. That is, if you assume $p$ (in this case, $p := P(x)$) and can deduce that $\neg p$, then you've shown that $(p \to \neg p)$, so by Modus Ponens $\neg p$ follows: $\neg p$ 
really is true.

Comment: One thing that I do not understand is the seemingly interchangable use of $P(x)$ and $\forall x P(x)$. The opposite to that $P$ is not true for any $x$ is not that $P$ is true for every $x$. The opposite is that there exist a $x$ for which $P$ is true.

Comment: They are not interchangeable, and they are not being interchanged. Once you instantiate $\forall x Q(x)$ with some particular $x'$, one about which you know nothing else (except that $Q(x')$ and whatever it implies), you're operating in that special context. You prove what you can, involving $x'$ — say, $R(x')$; finally, because you introduced an *arbitrary* $x'$ (NOT $7$!), you can dismiss the instantiation $x'$ and conclude that $\forall x R(x)$. It's not really necessary to introduce a fresh variable $x'$, you just have to be clear that it's just an "arbitrary thing such that $Q(\cdot)$".