# Proof of Negation of Quantified Statements

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic

In multiple sources, equivalent forms of the negations of quantified statements are stated as "theorem" instead of "definition," yet I have yet to find a satisfactory proof that rigorously proves the equivalences.

For instance, letting $P(x)$ be a predicate and $D$ be the domain of the predicate variable $x$, for the equivalence

$$\neg[\forall x\in D, P(x)]\equiv \exists x \in D \text{ such that } \neg P(x),$$

this [LibreText textbook](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Mathematical_Reasoning__Writing_and_Proof_(Sundstrom)/02%3A_Logical_Reasoning/2.04%3A_Quantifiers_and_Negations) explains it by writing (paraphrased to be consistent with above example):

> This is equivalent to saying that the truth set of the open sentence $P(x)$ is not the [domain $D$]. That is, there exists an element x in the [set $D$] such that $P(x)$ is false.

**My issue:**

Even though I do agree with this sentence, I feel that it is simply begging the question, that is, it is restating the theorem. The textbook *Discrete Mathematics with Applications* by Susanna Epp states that the theorem "follows immediately from the definitions", but I can't help but feel that as a "theorem", it should have a formal proof. Is it true that a theorem that follows immediately from definitions is still a theorem even without formal proof, or does a formal proof of this theorem exist? Or perhaps I am misunderstanding the definition of the word "theorem"?

*Clarification: I am not looking for an explanation of the equivalence. I understand it. I am simply looking for a proof since it is classified as a theorem.*

Comment: The details depend on the textbook... If Epp's textbook says that $\forall$ is primitive and $\exists$ is defined as $\lnot \forall \lnot$, then the result $\lnot \forall \equiv \exists \lnot$ follows easily by Double Negation.

Comment: In the on-line material you have linked, the quantifiers are explained by their truth condition: the *universal* one is true if the quantified formula holds for every object, while the existential one is true if the formula holds for some. Their "interdefinability" follows using negation.

Comment: See Epp (4th ed), page 109: "The general form for the negation of an existential statement follows immediately from the definitions of negation and of the truth values for existential and universal
statements."

Comment: The proof in Epp's book must use the def of *logical equivalence* (page 30) and double negation (page 31).

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673135/prove-that-forall-x-neg-px-iff-neg-exists-x-px)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Looks like the post you linked is the precise proof I was looking for. Thank you!